# How to multiply a matrix in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I cannot get this method to work. It intends to multiply a matrix by a given one. Could someone help me to correct it please?

```
    class Matriz
    {
        public double[,] structure;

        //Other class methods

        public void multiplyBy(Matrix m)
        {
            if (this.structure.GetLength(1) == m.structure.GetLength(0))
            {
                Matriz resultant = new Matriz(this.structure.GetLength(0), m.structure.GetLength(1));
                for (int i = 0; i < this.structure.GetLength(0) - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < m.structure.GetLength(1) - 1; j++)
                    {
                        resultant.structure[i, j] = 0;
                        for (int z = 0; z < this.structure.GetLength(1) - 1; z++)
                        {
                            resultant.structure[i, j] += this.structure[i, z] * m.structure[z, j];
                        }
                    }
                }
                this.structure= resultant.structure;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Selected matrixs cannot be multiply");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could someone please explain me the error in the code, I cannot see the difference with the related posts.

Comment: What error are you getting? What does "I cannot get this method," mean?

Comment: Here is a great resource from Microsoft on how to do Matrix operations with `C#` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj863137.aspx)

Comment: Rewrote the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read this [MSDN Magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj863137.aspx) by [James McCaffrey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee532098.aspx?sdmr=JamesMcCaffrey&sdmi=authors) and use the code below as an extension method. They use a jagged array which is more convenient and sometimes faster than a 2D array. Change any `data[i][j]` to `data[i,j]` to make the code work with a 2D array.

```
public static double[] MatrixProduct(this double[][] matrixA,
    double[] vectorB)
{
    int aRows=matrixA.Length; int aCols=matrixA[0].Length;
    int bRows=vectorB.Length;
    if (aCols!=bRows)
        throw new Exception("Non-conformable matrices in MatrixProduct");
    double[] result=new double[aRows];
    for (int i=0; i<aRows; ++i) // each row of A
        for (int k=0; k<aCols; ++k)
            result[i]+=matrixA[i][k]*vectorB[k];
    return result;
}
public static double[][] MatrixProduct(this double[][] matrixA,
    double[][] matrixB)
{
    int aRows=matrixA.Length; int aCols=matrixA[0].Length;
    int bRows=matrixB.Length; int bCols=matrixB[0].Length;
    if (aCols!=bRows)
        throw new Exception("Non-conformable matrices in MatrixProduct");
    double[][] result=MatrixCreate(aRows, bCols);
    for (int i=0; i<aRows; ++i) // each row of A
        for (int j=0; j<bCols; ++j) // each col of B
            for (int k=0; k<aCols; ++k)
                result[i][j]+=matrixA[i][k]*matrixB[k][j];
    return result;
}
public static double[][] MatrixCreate(int rows, int cols)
{
    // creates a matrix initialized to all 0.0s  
    // do error checking here?  
    double[][] result=new double[rows][];
    for (int i=0; i<rows; ++i)
        result[i]=new double[cols];
    // auto init to 0.0  
    return result;
}
```

Comment: If you are using `C` style matrices (one big array with each row in sequence) then you can index it with `data[i*cols+j]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the modified version of my method, as far as I've been testing this approach works fine.

```
    public void multiplicarPor(Matriz m)
    {
        if (this.estructura.GetLength(1) == m.estructura.GetLength(0))
        {
            Matriz resultante = new Matriz(this.estructura.GetLength(0), m.estructura.GetLength(1));
            for (int i = 0; i < this.estructura.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m.estructura.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    resultante.estructura[i, j] = 0;
                    for (int z = 0; z < this.estructura.GetLength(1); z++)
                    {
                        resultante.estructura[i, j] += this.estructura[i, z] * m.estructura[z, j];
                    }
                }
            }
            this.estructura = resultante.estructura;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No se pueden multiplicar estas matrices");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of writing to `estructura[i, j]` in the inner loop `z` write to a local variable `sum` and assign the value `estructura[i, j]=sum` after the loop. Also try not to call `GetLength()` so many times, but store its value in a local variable also.