# Fastest Way of Multiplying Arrays in Excel VBA and .NET

Tags: .net, vba, excel

I am trying to multiply arrays as quickly as I can.  There will be very large arrays, multiplied a lot of times.  I have the below code which uses a nested loop, is there any faster way of doing this?  I have array a() and b(), and I want to make sum(1) = a(1)*b(1) + a(1)*b(2) + a(1)*b(3) etc..

Currently I am in Excel VBA but I will be converting to VBA.NET soon.  How much faster should this be than running it in excel vba?  Are there faster methods in .Net that I could use?

```
Sub Test()
 ' Just creating the arrays
 Dim a() as Integer, b() as Integer, sum() as Integer, i as Integer, j as Integer
 ReDim a(1 to 3)
 ReDim b(1 to 3)
 ReDim sum(1 to 3)

 For i = 1 to 3 
  a(i) = 2 * i
  b(i) = 3 * i
 Next i

 ' This is my code I am  interested in
 For i = 1 to 3
  For j = 1 to 3
   sum(i) = sum(i) + a(i) * b(j)
  Next j
 Next i
```

Comment: "very large" means what exactly (or at least approximately), and "multiplied a lot of times" means what ? If you're concerned about performance, it helps to state more precisely what scale of numbers you're going to be working with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to multiply a matrix in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181020/how-to-multiply-a-matrix-in-c)

Comment: You `sum` seems to add up the rows of an outer product, and not matrix multiplication in the standard form. Standard matrix multiplication requires three loops with each element a sum `s(i,j) = SUM(a(i,k)*b(k,j),k=1..n)`

Comment: Where is `sum(i)` initialized? You are using un-initialized variables.

Comment: BTW In my experience `.NET` is 10× of `VBA` with math.

Comment: "very large" is maybe 20,000x50, depending.  And "a lot of times" is well over a million.  Ja, yes I should have been more clear, this isn't standard matrix multiplication. And are you saying .net is 10x faster than vba?

Comment: Someone answered with this link: http://innovatian.com/2010/03/parallel-matrix-multiplication-with-the-task-parallel-library-tpl/ but the answer was deleted for some reason.  I found the link very helpful so I thought I'd put it back up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your example is over-simplified, you can remove the inner loop by summing up your `b()` values, since

```
a*p + a*q + a*r + ... + a*z
```

is equivalent to

```
a * (p+q+r+...+z)
```

So:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim a(), b(), sum(), i As Long, j As Long, tmp, t, n As Long, tmp2
    ReDim a(1 To 20000)
    ReDim b(1 To 50)
    ReDim sum(1 To 20000)

    For i = 1 To 20000
        a(i) = i / 100
    Next i

    tmp2 = 0
    For i = 1 To 50
        b(i) = i / 100
        tmp2 = tmp2 + b(i)
    Next i

    t = Timer
    For n = 1 To 100
        For i = 1 To 20000
            For j = 1 To 50
             sum(i) = sum(i) + a(i) * b(j)
            Next j
        Next i
    Next n
    Debug.Print Timer - t ' ~5.5sec

    ReDim sum(1 To 20000)

    t = Timer
    For n = 1 To 100
        For i = 1 To 20000
            sum(i) = a(i) * tmp2
        Next i
    Next n
    Debug.Print Timer - t ' ~ 0.1 sec

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be faster:

```
' This is my code I am  interested in
For i = 1 to 3
  ai = a(i)
  sumi = 0#
  For j = 1 to 3
    sumi = sumi + ai * b(j)
  Next j
  sum(i) = sumi
Next i
```

Reducing the number of times you look up an array variable should improve things as modern processors take a lot longer to read from memory that to multiply values. I would consider also [loop unrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding), but you have to test with a high performance timer to see if it helps.

Comment: This is a good point, thanks. And I'll read up on loop unrolling